# Regex for ConstantText dot any text

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I neeed a c# regex for this 2 cases.

```
1)MyConstantText
2)MyConstantText.[a-zA-Z]
```

ex. 
My const text is Hello, then regex must match

```
Hello
Hello.ashdkajshd
```

Comment: Downvote reason: SO is not a "write my code for me" kind of website. show your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to *escape* when creating *regular expressions*:

```
  String text = "Hello";

  // Escape text as well as dot (\.)
  // Technically, you do want to escape "Hello", but since
  // text can be an arbitrary string, you'd better do it
  String pattern = Regex.Escape(text) + @"(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?";

  // Simple test
  Console.Write(Regex.Match("Hello.ashdkajshd", pattern).Value);
```

Remark: Please note, that *pattern*, provided in the *question* (`MyConstantText.[a-zA-Z]`) *doesn't match* the *sample* in the question (`"Hello.ashdkajshd"`) but `"Hello.a"` only. So, I've change the corresponding subpattern into `[a-zA-Z]+` (note `+`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is [tuto](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-csharp.html) for regex in c# ... if you got an error you can post it